# Can't find name 'user'?(TypeScript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, api, types

I don't understand why it gives me Error other component that i used does give anything and works just fine.Maybe problem is with typescript interface?

> Details.tsx

```
          import React, { FC } from "react";
          import App from "../App";
          import { IDetails } from "../types/Types";
          import { BiBookmark } from "react-icons/bi";
          import { BiShareAlt } from "react-icons/bi";
          interface DetailsProps {
            user: IDetails;
           }
           const Details: FC<DetailsProps> = ({user}) => {
           return (
            <>
             <div>
            <article className="description">
             <header className="header">
              <span style={{ margin: "1rem" }}> Job Details</span>
              <span style={{ margin: "18rem" }}>
               <BiBookmark />
               Save to my list
               </span>

              <span style={{ margin: "-12rem" }}>
                <BiShareAlt />
                Share
               </span>
             </header>
              <div className="span">-</div>
              <div className="Apply_now">APPLY NOW</div>
              <div>{user.title}</div>
             </article>
            </div>
             </>
            );
          };

          export default Details;
```

> Types.tsx

```
         export interface IDetails {
          name: string;
          title: string;
          headers: string;
          id: number;
          email: string;
          address: string | number;
          pictures: string[];
          updatedAt: string | number;
            }
```

> [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xp7Qc.png)
> [App.tsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBeUf.png)
> [Other component that i'm referring to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rABQN.png)

Comment: What line does the error occur on?

Comment: You require `user` prop but you don't pass it

Comment: In App.tsx just replace <Details /> to <Details user={yourUserData} />

Comment: I done it right after it occured(error){<Details user={IDetails} />} Error IDetails only refers to a type,but is being used as value here (also when i'm using other component that error doesn't occure)

Answer (score 0):

You do have to pass the `user=` prop to `<Details />`, otherwise the prop is missing and that's what the TypeScript error message is about.

On the other hand, you can get rid of the `<></>` Fragment surrounding your TSX

Comment: I done it right after it occured(error){<Details user={IDetails} />} Error IDetails only refers to a type,but is being used as value here (also when i'm using other component that error doesn't occure)